# How to configure java restassured library not to reuse the cookies

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, rest-assured

Am trying the reuse the restassured get call in the testng api tests, but the restassured instance in using the cookies received from the previous response. 
Tried RestAssured.reset(); but this doesn't help in flushing the cookies we got from earlier request/response.

Reason for this question - As the get endpoint behaves differently if there is a session cookie exist on the request.

```
@Test // TestNG test
public void test_1(){

    //Set Cookie
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder("COOKIENAME","COOKIEVALUE").setDomain("*.com").setPath("/").setExpiryDate(SOMELATERDATE).build();

    RestAssured.baseURI = https://ENV_URL;
    Response response = RestAssured.given().log().all()
        .cookies(new Cookies(cookie)).when().get("/END_POINT").then().extract().response().prettyPeek();

    RestAssured.reset();
}

@Test // TestNG test
public void test_2(){

    //Set Cookie
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder("COOKIENAME", "COOKIEVALUE").setDomain("*.com").setPath("/").setExpiryDate(SOMELATERDATE).build();

    RestAssured.baseURI = https://ENV_URL;
    // Still Reuses the cookie received from previous response
    Response response = RestAssured.given().log().all()
        .cookies(new Cookies(cookie)).when().get("/END_POINT").then().extract().response().prettyPeek();

    RestAssured.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CookieFilter. If you want to exclude the a particular cookie you can use the following code.

```
    @Test 
    public void sampletest(){

        CookieFilter cookieFilter = new CookieFilter(); 
        Response response = RestAssured.given().
         cookie("foo", "bar").
         filter(cookieFilter). // Reuse the same cookie filter
                      // if "foo" is stored in cookieFilter it won't be applied because it's already applied explicitly
 expect().
         statusCode(200).
 when().
         get("/y");

    }
```